# Ubuntu Server 12.04, Wifi problems

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server

When I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, I selected the ethernet adapter because I will use that most often; however, I would like to use wifi sometimes as well.

This is how far I've gotten with this problem.

```
lspci 
02:00.0 Network Controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection

iwconfig
wlan0  IEEE a/b/g/n  BSSID=off/any  Mode=Managed  Access Point=Not-Associated TX-Power=off  Retry Long Limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off  Power Management:off
```

I tried to do `iwconfig wlan0 up` but that doesn't work either.  The error message said something along the lines of **rfkill** but I'm not connected to the Internet to download that particular program.

Any help here would be great

Comment: did you solve the problem yet ?

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. What I was trying to do was use the WiFi as a backup just in case my network went down.

Comment: what does it say exactly? does it say hard blocked or soft blocked? Please include the output of `sudo iwconfig wlan0 up`

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch on your WiFi switch
2. Enter the following command

   ```
   rfkill list all
   ```
3. You will get something like this

   ```
   0 : sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   ```
4. If any value (Highlighted above) is displaying `yes`
5. Enter the following command

   ```
   rfkill unblock all
   ```
6. Check your WiFi Status Again.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is making sure that the drivers for your wireless card are correctly installed. And having a good look through the [wireless troubleshooting.](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html)

> Check for device recognition Open a Terminal (Applications →
>   Accessories → Terminal) and type the command: sudo lshw -C network
>
> You should see an output, along with the words "CLAIMED, UNCLAIMED,
>   ENABLED or DISABLED"
>
> Claimed - this indicates a driver is loaded but not functioning, see
>   the section called “Using Windows Wireless Drivers”
>
> Unclaimed - there is no driver loaded, see the section called “Using
>   Windows Wireless Drivers”.
>
> Enabled - there is a driver loaded, see the section called “Check for
>   a connection to the router”.
>
> Disabled - see the section called “Check that the device is on”.

This is from the ubuntu troubleshooting section on wireless. Try the following command.

***sudo lshw -C network***

This should give you a better idea of what your wireless card is doing.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I get home

Comment: I tried that and looked over the the link you posted.  The wireless troubleshooting puts me in a loop because the device is on but then the command lshw -C network tells me that my wifi is disabled so look to is it on...cycle repeats.  I may try to install the wifi drivers via NDISWrapper